# Proof of minimal element of a subset without using GLB property

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> How do we prove that if a nonempty subset $E$ of $\mathbb Z$ is bounded below then it has a minimal element without explicitly making use of the greatest-lower bound property (or lub property)?

A different proof used the glb property of $\mathbb R$ and *assumed it had already shown* $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb R$ to say $E$ must have a greatest lower bound.

*I was wondering if the proof below is correct if we do not explicitly use(reference) glb property.*

*Proof.*

Let $s$ be a lower bound of $E$ and let $F$ be the set of all lower bounds of E. If $r \in E$ then there must exist an $s \in \mathbb Z$ such that $$s\le r \lt s+1$$ where $s+1 \notin F$.

Since  there are no integers between $s$ and $(s+1)$ from the above inequality we can deduce $s=r.$

Therefore, we get $F \ \cap \ E = \{r\}.$ Since $r$ is both an element of $E$ and a lower bound of $E$ it is the minimal element of $E$ as well.

Comment: @carmichael561 So sorry about that! I meant a subset of the integers. Staring at the screen too long.

Comment: Why the down vote? Itll be helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $s$ be a lower bound of $E$ and let $F$ be the set of all lower bounds of E. If $r \in E$ then there must exist an $s \in \mathbb Z$ such that $$s\le r \lt s+1$$ where $s+1 \notin F$.

This doesn't make any sense. You give two definitions for $s$, first as a lower bound of $E$ and then as the floor of $r$, but they don't coincide. $6$ is a lower bound of $\{10,11\}$ but if we pick $r=11$ then the value that satisfies the inequality is $s=11$. You have no way of knowing that the floor of $r$ is a lower bound of $E$, and as my example shows it sometimes isn't true.

Comment: Thanks I see that. Do you know what a starting approach would be to proving this?

Comment: @Red That depends on how much you're willing to cheat when you say "without using GLB." For example, you can prove it by induction, but induction is really the same thing as GLB.